# Failed to pull image "docker4nitin/tg_bot:v2": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, yaml, runtime-error

I have created a image "docker4nitin/tg_bot:v2" and pushed into the dockerhub. I have created a k8 deployment file to deploy it but it is failing to pull the image.
This is deployment.yml file

[deployment.yml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8Ecx.png)
Please fix this issue. I'm literally tired of finding the solution but did not find any.

I want to deploy it in K8

Comment: Where are you deploying this? What happens when you pull a different image, some other common public image from Dockerhub, like nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine with your image. I just tested it by creating following deployment and kubernetes pulls it fine.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  replicas: 1 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tgbot
        image: docker4nitin/tg_bot:v2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Here are the events that occurred when I pulled it on my end.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From                   Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----                   -------
  Normal   Scheduled  4m1s                  bin-packing-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/test-deployment-6bf6bbbfb5-mlrgp to ip-10-250-0-97.eu-central-1.compute.internal
  Normal   Pulling    4m1s                  kubelet                Pulling image "docker4nitin/tg_bot:v2"
  Normal   Pulled     3m43s                 kubelet                Successfully pulled image "docker4nitin/tg_bot:v2" in 17.153014569s
  Normal   Created    2m8s (x5 over 3m42s)  kubelet                Created container tgbot
  Normal   Started    2m8s (x5 over 3m41s)  kubelet                Started container tgbot
  Normal   Pulled     2m8s (x4 over 3m40s)  kubelet                Container image "docker4nitin/tg_bot:v2" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff    2m7s (x9 over 3m39s)  kubelet                Back-off restarting failed container
```

if you pay attention, image pull works fine but there's something wrong with your container itself that is causing the backoff of the container. Maybe posting the specific error here is more useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the below manually and try your deployment

```bash
docker pull docker4nitin/tg_bot:v2
```